# How to find the inverse function involving the exponential function?

Tags: calculus, inverse

Given: $f(x)= \dfrac{e^x}{1+9e^x}$ ,

what steps would I take to find its inverse? I tried following the steps on finding the inverse of a normal function but I keep getting one of the variables to cancel out.

Comment: Do you mean $e^x/(1+9e^x)$? Parentheses are important.

Comment: What is a normal function?

Comment: The question doesn't include the parentheses. And by normal, I mean't a function like y=x+2/x-1 (wasn't sure how to explain it any other way).

Comment: No parentheses? And it's not $\frac{e^x}{1+9e^x}$, it's just $e^x/1+9e^x$ the way you wrote it? But $e^x/1=e^x$, so $e^x/1+9e^x=e^x+9e^x=10e^x$.

Comment: The question itself didn't include the parentheses but I see what you mean and how it should. It's exactly how you wrote it bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to solve the equation
$$y=\frac{e^x}{1+9e^x}$$
for $x$ as function of $y$.
$$(1+9e^x)y=e^x$$
$$y+9e^xy=e^x$$
$$y=e^x-9e^xy$$
$$y=e^x(1-9y)$$
$$\frac y{1-9y}=e^x$$
$$e^x=\frac y{1-9y}$$
$$\ln(e^x)=\ln(\frac y{1-9y})$$
$$x=\ln(\frac y{1-9y})$$